# After moving my site to Amazon instance, special character do not display in correct format

Tags: html, mysql, character-encoding, special-characters, php-5.5

My old server is working perfectly with special character but when I moved whole source code on Amazon instance whole site look weird because of  special character.

Below are configuration on newly created instance on Amazon

```
PHP Version : PHP Version 5.3.29-Ubuntu/trusty/Sergey/r10 (amazon instance)
              PHP Version 5.3.3-7+squeeze19 (old server)    

Mysql Version : 5.5.46 (amazon instance)
                5.1.73 (old server)

Data base collation : "utf8_general_ci"
Tables Collation : "utf8_general_ci"
Fields Collation : "utf8_general_ci"
Set Content Type in php style as well as html style under <head> tag

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;  charset=utf-8" />
header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

But still special character issue can not be resolved still content display like

Fetch from database and display in PHP page it won't display in correct format

```
"Tablet Caf� in Bibliotheek Ommen"
```

And when I try to put static string in PHP page it displays correct format.

```
"Tablet Café in Bibliotheek Ommen"
```

Also to make a `href` link I have created custom function to replace special character with "_" so the URL will not break.

```
$special_character = array(" ","<",">","#","%",",","{","}","|","\\","^","~","[","]","`",";","/","?",":","@","=","&","$",",","(",")",",","'",".","ë","À","Á","Â","Ã","Ä","Å","Æ","Ç","Ð","È","É","Ê","Ë","Ì","Í","Î","Ï","Ñ","Œ","Ò","Ó","Ô","Õ","Ö","Ø","ß","Š","Ù","Ú","Û","Ü","Ý","Ÿ","à","á","â","ã","ä","å","æ","ç","¢","è","é","ê","ë","ì","í","î","ï","ñ","œ","ò","ó","ô","õ","ö","ø","ð","š","ù","ú","û","ü","ý","ÿ","€","ƒ","£","¥","…","ª","º","¹","²","³","¼","½","¾","¿","ˆ","‹","›","¦","«","»","×","©","™","®","±","÷","µ","¶","¤","°","‰","§","·","¬","•","¡","†","‡","!");
```

and then using `str_replace` my script will replace all special character (which are in above array) with "_"

```
str_replace($special_character,"_",strip_tags($fetch_art[$i]['title']))
```

So now my URL is "www.xyz.com/news/Tablet_Caf�_in_Bibliotheek_Ommen".
(in my old server is working fine)

But when I use utf8_encode it works fine. I don't want to use with utf8_encode so Kindly suggest alternate way to display special character.

Does the Amazon server need any other configuration?

Answer (score 1):

The black diamond (�) is the browser's way of saying it does not know how to display a particular character. It comes from having latin1 characters, but telling the browser to display utf8 characters.

So check:

1. the bytes in your client are utf8
2. you are connecting with utf8 `set_charset('utf8')` or `SET NAMES utf8`
3. the table/column says `CHARACTER SET utf8`
4. the meta tag in the header of the html says `UTF-8`.

(Do not use utf8_encode or any other transformation functions.)